# Efficient way to use api request header in controller, models in Node Express Js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I am pretty much new to Node JS. We do have a requirement to use the request header from router to model class.
Let us assume an simple router

```
router.ts
```

```
router.delete(
  '/sample/:id',
  validateRequest(),
  async function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const solution: string = req.header('Some Header Value') || '';
      await Controller.someMethods(req.params.id, solution);
      return res.json(new HttpResponse('SUCCESS', {}, {}));
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  },
);
```

This is our router, Here we should be able to read "solution" in controller, service, and model classes. Right now we have passed this as an argument to different components. Is there any better approach to read the header value which is in the current request scope?
Similarly using components in spring framework, or sesison management or any other better approach other than passing the header value as an argument at each component level.

regards
Eresh

Comment: not really. You end up having to pass something or another.

Comment: Hmm! Any common approach across the node js, like a reusable component?

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR; There is no other way than just mapping it manually.

Express is quite minimalistic so we don't such abstractions as Spring, the truth is that Node.js is different from Java. In Java we spawn a thread per request, so every request has a single thread. Whereas Node.js is async and single-threaded, so multiple requests share the same thread so you need to pass the values down your calls because there is no out-of-the-box solution on storing global values for a request.

If you want to have an access to the headers somewhere inside an application you could build a system that does so. The first step is to add the middleware that stores the headers in service with a unique ID associated with it and somehow passes this ID down the road. Then whenever you know the ID you could call the service to get the data for you, though you still will need to pass the ID down the road. I think you should not care about that, and that is okay. I would refactor your code in a way that a `Controller` methods access `req` and `res` then all the logic of working with these objects will be incapsulated here, whereas the service layer will expect raw data that know nothing about the transport layer that controllers operate with. Thus you can call services from another service, because they know nothing about the request and response.

FWIW, if you need a better framework use Nest.js, it is great and advanced, also it uses decorators (in a way similar to annotations in Spring). For instance you could just inject the header value as a call argument for your method in the following way `@Header("some-header") solution: string`

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Ayzrian for the detail, Will try the option.